# How can I create links that send you to a nested view ionic/angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create links on **tabs.home** state as you can see the list with the links to redirect me to the inner views of about page. For more informations you can see this codepen: http://codepen.io/albpower/pen/bEeqjj?editors=1014 .
Below is part of the app.js where the states/views are declared for the templates HTML code please see the codepend link above.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('tabs', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  .state('tabs.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'home-tab': {
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabs.about', {
    url: "/about",
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'about-tab': {
        templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabs.about.page1', {
    url: "/page1",
    views: {
      'about-page': {
        templateUrl: "templates/about-page1.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabs.about.page2', {
    url: "/page2",
    views: {
      'about-page': {
        templateUrl: "templates/about-page2.html"
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

});
```

I've tried adding ui-sref="tabs.about.page2" to list items didn't worked. Second way I've tried is using href="#/tab/page2" didn't worked. Also I've tried using custom functions using $state.go('tabs.about.page2') but still the same result. At the address bar it is shown the url to that state properly but no content is shown.

Comment: u can pass $stateParams to tabs.about state as tab index and open it..!

Comment: Can you explain again please, an example snippet would be welcomed or just modify the codepen.